# using docker and nginx but always connection refused by backend server

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

now I am making a server with express, react, docker, nginx

but nginx can't connect with nginx
here's the log and nginx.conf and docker-compose file

and also I can connect with localhost:8080/api
but I can't connect with localhost/api
what is wrong?

nginx.conf

```
upstream frontend {
server  127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream backend {
server  127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
listen \*:80;
server_name localhost;

    # ignore cache frontend
    location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }
    
    location / {
        root /var/www/frontend;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

}
```

error.log

```
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.1
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.10.76-linuxkit
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
2023/07/15 18:33:41 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
2023/07/15 18:34:28 [error] 25#25: *2 directory index of "/var/www/frontend/" is forbidden, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2023/07/15 18:34:28 [error] 25#25: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
2023/07/15 18:34:35 [error] 24#24: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/", host: "localhost"
2023/07/15 18:34:51 [error] 24#24: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/", host: "localhost"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
volumes:
build_folder: null

services:
frontend:
build:
context: ./wordPad_front
args:
API_URL: "\*"
environment:
\- REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8000
volumes:
\- ./wordPad_front/:/frontend
\- build_folder:/frontend/build
tty: true

nginx:
build: ./wordPad_nginx
ports:
\- 80:80
volumes:
\- build_folder:/var/www/frontend
\- ./wordPad_nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
depends_on:
\- frontend

backend:
build: ./wordPad_back
command: "node index.js"
ports:
\- "8080:8080"
depends_on:
postgre:
condition: service_healthy

postgre:
build: ./wordPad_db
volumes:
\- ./wordPad_db/data:/data
ports:
\- "5432:5432"
env_file:
\- "./wordPad_db/.env"
healthcheck:
test: \["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-d", "db_prod"\]
interval: 30s
timeout: 60s
retries: 5
start_period: 80s

adminer:
image: adminer
ports:
\- 6638:8080
```

I hope that at least I can notice what I should do or what I should learn

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also your docker compose file is invalid formatted. BTW: "127.0.0.1" is the loopback interface, and not any of your container instances IPs

Answer (score 0):

In a container, `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` means the container itself.

Your upstream servers are defined as having the IP address `127.0.0.1`, which means that they are inside the Nginx container. They aren't, so that's why it doesn't work.

To fix it, you can use the Docker compose service names of the upstream containers and change your Nginx config to

```
upstream frontend {
  server  frontend:3000;
}

upstream backend {
  server  backend:8080;
}
```

Note that for communication between containers on the same Docker network, the port numbers you use are the un-mapped port numbers. I.e. it should be the ports that your frontend and backend are listening on.

Read [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for more information on Docker Compose networking.

Comment: you are fxxxing gineus thanks a lot reallly